# What do I need to set a bounty to my question

Tags: support, bounty

I am interested in how to setup a bounty to a question. I [searched](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=bounty) for the tag [bounty] here but all the questions are about the rewardeing of bounties. If I overlooked the explanation please link me the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Help Center > Reputation & Moderation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for an explanation about bounties. Most important for you is that you need at least 50 rep to spend on a bounty.

Comment: I was looking for this page. Thanks!